# Tracking down edits to my /etc/hosts file

Tags: linux, debian, cron, hosts-file

Every hour at :49, my hosts file is being replaced with the following:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-1999 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

127.0.0.1       localhost

# *********<D2><D4><CF><C2><C4><DA><C8><DD>Ϊ360<B0><B2>ȫ<CE><C0>ʿΪ<C3><E2><D2><U+07FB><FA><C6><F7><B9><B7>ľ<C2><U+DCA1><B6><BE><CB><F9><CC><ED><BC><D3>******************
127.0.0.1  yu.8s7.net
127.0.0.1  1.jopanqc.com
127.0.0.1  2.joppnqq.com
127.0.0.1  wg.47255.com
127.0.0.1  1.joppnqq.com
127.0.0.1  xxx.m111.biz
127.0.0.1  1.jopenqc.com
127.0.0.1  1.jopenkk.com
127.0.0.1  xxx.vh7.biz
127.0.0.1  xxx.j41m.com
127.0.0.1  3.joppnqq.com
127.0.0.1  d.93se.com
127.0.0.1  www.868wg.com
127.0.0.1  xxx.mmma.biz
127.0.0.1  ilove.com
127.0.0.1  tp.shpzhan.cn
127.0.0.1  www.tomwg.com
127.0.0.1  www.cike007.cn
127.0.0.1  www.22aaa.com
127.0.0.1  xx.exiao01.com
127.0.0.1  www.exiao01.com
127.0.0.1  www.exiao01.com
127.0.0.1  new.749571.com
127.0.0.1  xtx.kv8.info
127.0.0.1  cao.kv8.info
127.0.0.1  1.jopmmqq.com
127.0.0.1  171817.171817.com
127.0.0.1  d2.llsging.com
127.0.0.1  down.malasc.cn
127.0.0.1  llboss.com
127.0.0.1  nx.51ylb.cn
127.0.0.1  my.531jx.cn
127.0.0.1  qqq.dzydhx.com
127.0.0.1  qqq.hao1658.com
127.0.0.1  www.333292.com
127.0.0.1  down.18dd.net
127.0.0.1  up.22x44.com
# *********<BD><E1><CA><F8>******************
# *********<D2><D4><CF><C2><C4><DA><C8><DD>Ϊ360<B0><B2>ȫ<CE><C0>ʿΪ<C3><E2><D2>ߴŵ<FA><BB><FA>dummycom<B2><A1><B6><BE><CB><F9><CC><ED><BC><D3>******************
127.0.0.1  gxgxy.net^M
# *********<C3><E2><D2>ߴŵ<FA><BB><FA>dummycom<BD><E1><CA><F8>******************
```

I've tried using `auditctl` to track the changes like so:

```
# /sbin/auditctl -w /etc/hosts -p wa -k hosts-file
```

But every hour, it's replaced, and running `/sbin/ausearch -f /etc/hosts` shows nothing. When I manually edit the file, ausearch shows my change.

I've looked both at my user's crontab and root's crontab, and I see nothing running at :49 that might be the culprit.

What might be doing this and how can I stop it? I'm running Debian jessie/testing.

Comment: Are you sure auditd is running?

Comment: It is. When I set up the rule to watch the hosts file and then manually edit it with vim, ausearch yields a line that indicates that vim edited the file at the time I edited it.

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674439/linux-etc-hosts-content) seems to suggest it's from [Likewise](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LikewiseOpen), though I'm not sure why Likewise would need to modify /etc/hosts like that.

Comment: Hm. I don't have Likewise installed, and I'm currently ack'ing my entire harddrive for one of the strings in the file to see if it's coming from elsewhere. This is really confusing.

Comment: Would it be helpful to install a `incron` to monitor `/etc/hosts`, and run a `ps aux` to log all running procedures when the file is modified?

Comment: I added an `incron` rule and tested it. I hadn't seen that, thank you! Nothing running as root at the time IN_MODIFY looks suspicious, though.

Comment: In my case, I think the `f5fpc` enterprise VPN client is wiping it on reconnect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, dear. I just found this, which has exactly the symptoms I was describing earlier: https://askubuntu.com/questions/440919/how-to-deal-with-malware-on-my-laptop

Looks like I'm wiping the system this weekend.